# Peripheral included services - iOS

Tags: objective-c, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

I have an application which plays the Peripheral role and starts advertisement using *CoreBluetooth* framework. I successfully add a service and advertise it, and successfully discover it using another Central application.

However, when I want to add some secondary services to my primary service, they aren't discovered by other central applications.

On the **peripheral side**, I add services to a `CBPeripheralManager` object:

```
- (void)AddService:(BOOL )primary {
    CBMutableService *Service = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:_service_UUID primary:primary];
    if (primary)
        _mainService = Service;

    NSMutableArray *characteristics = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (MyCharacterstic *characteristic in _service_characteristics)
        [characteristics addObject: [characteristic GetObject]];
    Service.characteristics = characteristics;
    [_manager addService: Service];
}

- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didAddService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {
    if (!service.isPrimary)
        [_services addObject:service];
}
```

When all secondary services have been added, I call the following function to start advertisement:

```
- (void)StartAdvertisement {
    _mainService.includedServices = _services;
    [_manager startAdvertising:@{CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: _LocalName,
                                 CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: @[_mainService.UUID]}];
}
```

On the **central side**, I try to discover included services:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {
    for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
        if ([_service_UUID containsObject: service.UUID]) {
            [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
            [peripheral discoverIncludedServices:nil forService:service];
        }
    }
}
```

It calls the following delegate function, but it always returns an empty array for included services:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverIncludedServicesForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {
     for (CBService *services in service.includedServices) {
         NSLog(@"Service: %@", services);
     }
}
```

Comment: You need your secondary services to be held in a property too, otherwise they will be released once your `AddService` function (which should be called `addService`,  by convention) exits.

Comment: @Paulw11 Indeed, I keep references in `_services` after the `didAddService` delegate is called, and when I log `_mainService` object, the 'includedServices` is fulfilled. But they are not discovered in central and I don't have any idea.